# Unity3d gets stuck when converting NSString to char* and returning it

Tags: c#, objective-c, macos, plugins, unity-game-engine

I have a function

```
char* OpenFolderDialog()
{
    NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];
    [openDlg setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
    [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
    [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:NO];   

    if ([openDlg runModal] != NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) return nil;

    NSString *url = [[openDlg URLs] lastObject];
    return (char*)[url UTF8String];
}
```

When I call this in Unity3d my application hangs up. If I hardcode an NSString variable and return it using the same return statement it works fine. 
I also put this url in an alert box and had that displayed and it works perfect. So there is some issue in returning the url to my Unity3d code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check what the `url` is, when it's not working? An how do you process the return value from this method?

Comment: @d4Rk
Yup I checked the url, it was a proper path like /Users/zohaib/Desktop etc.
I just assign it to a string when in Unity.

I got this working but with a very crappy workaround. 

filepath = DialogBoxMacOS.OpenBrowseDialog().ToString();

I made an alert. Assigned this url to its message string. 
Then retrieved it and sent it to Unity and it worked.

[alert setInformativeText:url];
NSString* hello = [alert informativeText];
return (char*)[hello UTF8String];